# How to convert VARIANT to integer

Tags: c++, c++11, com, variant

I am converting VARIANT to int using boost::lexical_cast as below :

```
component.m_id= boost::lexical_cast<int>(id.intVal);
```

But looks like i am getting garbage value here : id.intVal. What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: please go through this document http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast` has no use with `VARIANT`. What is the value of `id.vt` in this context?

Comment: the value is :  id.vt 8

Comment: [`8` is `VT_BSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so try `component.m_id = boost::lexical_cast<int>(id.bstrVal);`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really know the type of what the variant holds (in your example, it seems to be a string represented as a VT_BSTR), the best and safest way is to call the Windows API [VariantChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221258.aspx) (or VariantChangeTypeEx is localization is an issue); here is an example (not boost-specific):

```
VARIANT vIn;
VariantInit(&vIn);
vIn.vt = VT_BSTR;
vIn.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"12345678");

VARIANT vOut;
VariantInit(&vOut);

// convert the input variant into a 32-bit integer
// this works also for other compatible types, not only BSTR
if (S_OK == VariantChangeType(&vOut, &vIn, 0, VT_I4))
{
    // now, you can safely use the intVal member
    printf("out int: %i\n", vOut.intVal);
}    

VariantClear(&vOut);
VariantClear(&vIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **boost::get**. But not for casting. It is for extracting the real type from the boost::variant.  Example :
suppose you have :

```
boost::variant<bool, int, double> v myVariant;
myVariant = true;
```

you have to use :

```
bool value = boost::get<bool>(myVariant);
```

**and not**

```
double value = boost::get<double>(myVariant);
```

otherwise it will crashes.

Once you have the value you can cast it.

If you don't know the type you set on you boost variant, you have to use : **boost::apply_visitor<>** like in the example in the link below, at the end of the page :

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html

but that means you have to do it for each type in your boost::variant